# <figcaption> on left of <img> and both vertically aligned

Tags: image, vertical-alignment, figure

I'm trying to do a simple caption on the left of my `<img>` and vertically aligning them (i.e. text is aligned to the middle of the image on the right).

```
<figure><img style="float:right" alt="qrcode_vcard" src="/assets/pic.png" />
 <figcaption>My caption goes here. How do I make it aligned to the middle rather than the top.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I can float the image to the right but the caption is aligned to the top. I want to align it to the middle. I would also like to keep the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple options, using either CSS Grid or CSS flexbox.

With flexbox:

```css
figure {
  /* forcing the use of CSS flexbox for layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* reversing the direction of the contents, to ensure
     the image is placed to the right (in left-to-right)
     locales, but to the left in right-to-left locales): */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  /* aligning the items to the center of the flow-axis
     (the direction of the contents): */
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<figure><img alt="qrcode_vcard" src="https://fillmurray.com/200/200" />
  <figcaption>My caption goes here. How do I make it aligned to the middle rather than the top.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Or, with CSS Grid:

```css
figure {
  /* forcing the use of CSS grid for layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* specifying that contents should be placed
     in columns rather than rows: */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  /* setting the text direction to right-to-left flow: */
  direction: rtl;
  /* aligning the contents to the centre of the flow-axis: */
  align-items: center;
  /* defining a 10px gutter between grid-items: */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<figure><img alt="qrcode_vcard" src="https://fillmurray.com/200/200" />
  <figcaption>My caption goes here. How do I make it aligned to the middle rather than the top.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[JS Fiddle demonstrations](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jq4ydkn0/).

References:

- "[Basic concepts of flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)."
- "[Basic concepts of grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)."
- [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).
- [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [`grid-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap).